# Measure object size without using tesnsorflow

Tags: android, object-detection

Currently i am working on measure object size from captured image. My idea is to measure object size from capture image which captured by camera2 api library. I too much research of it and found most of solution with tensor flow but i need to do without use of tensorflow.

So is it possible to do this without tensor flow?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not possible to calculate size of an object from a single image, fully correctly.

As a simple example, if you have a beach ball that's 0.5 meter in size, 1 meter away from the camera.  How would you distinguish it from a beach ball that's 0.25 meters in size, 0.5 meters away?  (the actual numbers may be a bit different, since optics has some reciprocal relationships instead of linear ones).

If you have a depth camera, or stereo cameras, you can do actual determination of object distance, and then calculate object size.  Otherwise, you can use ML-like approaches to make guesses like "this is a chair and chairs are usually this big" or "the lighting indicates this object is at least X meters big".

Systems like [ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar) do multi-frame analysis with the camera moving to understand the 3D scene.  But again, that's multiple frames over time, not a single image.

Maybe you can use ARCore, if TensorFlow-based approaches aren't an option.  Otherwise, you need to find structure-from-motion libraries (SLAM, etc) but you'd still need multiple images as input.